# Creating Generic XSLT to parse Text file to XML

Tags: xslt-2.0, text-parsing

I had been assigned a task to use XSLT to convert tons of text files into different XML. As I am extremely new to this, I took a shot at it myself.Here is what I've found that would do the trick: 1) XSLT started to support this in v2.0, and 2) unparsed-text() is the way to go

So I have finally got it working to parse a file into XML, but the method I used requires me to have an XSLT file per each text file(1 to 1) due to a lot of needed hardcoding for fucntions like xsl:analyze-string and I am now trying to find a way that can parse all of my files with just 1 generic XSLT. Please note that the text files might contain different patterns, but if I can find a way to generically parse more than 1 file(with similar patterns) then I will be happy.

Here are 2 sample files that I have:

```
***********
* Sample1
***********

SET:              <block>    

      NAME:  Name1      <string>       /* some words/words */

!---end---        </block>    

SET:          <block>    
      NAME:   Name2     <string>    

      NESTEDSET:            <block>    
         VALUE1:    FIRST       <string>    
      ---end---

      NESTEDSET:            <block>    
         VALUE1:    SECOND      <string>    
         VALUE2:        ANYVALUE    <string>    
      ---end---

!---end---        </block>
```

and below are 2nd Sample file

```
**********
* Sample2
**********

NEW_SET: <block> 
  NAME: Set1                <string>
*        Col1  Col2  Col3   
  ENTRY: 1     Win   0.2       <integer,string,floating>
  ENTRY: 2     Win   0.3       <integer,string,floating>       
  ENTRY: 3     Lost  0.4       <integer,string,floating>       

!--- end of block ---                  </block>
```

here is the xslt that I created for sample1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="sourcefile" 
        select="unparsed-text('file:///C:/Users/aUser/Desktop/Sample1.txt')"/>

    <xsl:template name="text2xml">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="translate(normalize-space($sourcefile), ' ',',')"         
            regex="SET:.*?!---end---" flags="s">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <SET>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(NAME):,([^,]*)">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:element name="{(regex-group(1))}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="(regex-group(2))"/>
                            </xsl:element>          
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>               
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." 
                        regex="NESTEDSET.*?,---end---" flags="s">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <NESTEDSET>
                                <xsl:analyze-string select="." 
                                    regex="(VALUE1|VALUE2):,([^,]*)">
                                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                                        <xsl:element name="{(regex-group(1))}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="(regex-group(2))"/>
                                        </xsl:element>          
                                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                                </xsl:analyze-string>
                            </NESTEDSET>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string> 
                </SET>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="text2xml"/>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the xml output for this xslt is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SET>
   <NAME>Name1</NAME>
</SET>
<SET>
   <NAME>Name2</NAME>
   <NESTEDSET>
      <VALUE1>FIRST</VALUE1>
   </NESTEDSET>
   <NESTEDSET>
      <VALUE1>SECOND</VALUE1>
      <VALUE2>ANYVALUE</VALUE2>
   </NESTEDSET>
</SET>
```

May I ask if there is a better way to do this? to not hardcode anything and can create something generic that other files containing the same pattern can be used? 
the way I am doing it(from my understanding) is that I am using unparsed-text() to force a text file into a single line then hardcoding a string(in regex) to tell it where to start/stop looking. so just want to look for a better way. 
Thank you all for any suggestions/feedbacks.

Comment: So the first sample has e.g. `SET:` and the second e.g. `NEW_SET:`? Well you can write a regular expression with e.g. `\w*SET:`  to cover that for instance. But you have not shown which result you want to create for the second sample.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response, that is def a good lookup. May i ask if you were me which have to use XSLT, would you use a different method to parse these text files to XML as oppose to what I've used(unparsed-text() then analyze-string())? are there any other way to parse these text file without hardcoding anything? Thanks in advance for your suggestions/feedbacks